# Batch ECHO %varname% just saying "Echo is on."

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, echo

So I was tasked with making a batch file that does a few specific things. I've never worked with batch before, and I'm finding it hard to find tutorials on what exactly I need. (I've done basic tutorials)

I'm trying to get the most currently edited file from a directory. The only thing I've came up with (and I've noticed other people said to do) is a for loop of files in the directory sorted by date and then just get the first file and break the loop.

Some problems:
1) My loop never breaks
2) My ECHO %variable% doesn't work at the end.

```
@echo off
SET count=0
FOR /f %%i in ('DIR Y:\ /B /O:-D') DO (
IF count==0 (
SET NewestFile=%%i
SET count=1
)
)
@echo on
ECHO %NewestFile%
```

When I run this, I get:

```
C:\>testing.bat
C:\>ECHO
ECHO is on.
```

I am 100% new to Batch. Maybe I'm doing something that this is really picky about? (Other StackOverflow questions have been solved by people just adding aa space or stuff like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is never met because the string `count` is never equal to the string `0`. You need

```
if !count!==0 (
  set NewestFile=%%i
  set count=1
)
```

But then you also need delayed expansion (at the beginning of your batch file):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

The problem here is that you need to tell the batch file that there is a variable. Like `foo` in Perl won't magically resolve to the contents of the `$foo` variable `count` in your batch file isn't equivalent to `%count%` (the variable contents) or `!count!` (the same, but with delayed expansion).

Delayed expansion is necessary because the whole `for` loop is parsed at once. And `cmd` replaces normal (`%foo%`) variables with their contents during parsing so that during execution only the values remain. So once execution reaches the `if` there would be the condition `0==0` because that's what `count`'s value was before the loop. Delayed expansion (using the `!foo!` syntax) expands the variables immediately prior to execution, so this does not happen.

For more help on delayed expansion you can read `help set`.

Another way would be to just use absence or presence of the `count` variable:

```
SET count=
FOR /f %%i in ('DIR Y:\ /B /O:-D') DO (
  IF not defined count (
    SET NewestFile=%%i
    SET count=1
  )
)
```

This works around the problem above because there is no variable to replace during parsing. All we're doing is a run-time check whether the variable `count` exists.

Comment: *phew* Okay. I tried both of those options and they work. I'll research a little more on !variable!, as well. Thank you!

Comment: I've expanded the answer a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

If you supplied accurate code then you want to get the first line - and this is one way to do that.

```
@echo off
FOR /f %%i in ('DIR Y:\ /B /O:-D') DO SET "NewestFile=%%i" & goto :done
:done
ECHO %NewestFile%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `dir` command to list the files in ascending order instead of descending order, you can use this one-liner which doesn't need any of the common bizarre cmd.exe scripting hacks. It just keeps the last line of output in the `NewestFile` variable (I guess it might qualify as a cmd.exe scripting hack, but I don't think it qualifies as bizarre):

```
for /f %%i in ('DIR Y:\ /B /O:D') do set NewestFile=%%i
```